# filtar table dropdown livewire with Laravel

Tags: laravel, filter, dropdown, laravel-livewire

I have this livewire component which filters a table based on the two dropdown buttons. one is called Instance and the other Job. I would like to find a way to filter both buttons.

in this way or I pass it to render updatejob or updateinstance. So only one of the two buttons works. is there any way to make them both work?

in the sense that if I use a public variable to which I pass the query results through the two methods it does not allow me to do the pagination since I would operate its public variable that allows collections

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;
    use Livewire\WithPagination;
    
    use App\Models\Task;
    use Livewire\Component;
    
    class TableTodo extends Component
    {
        use WithPagination;
    
        public $instance;
        public $job;
        public $jobs;
        // public $tasks;
        public $instances;
    
        public function updatinginstance()
        {
            $this->resetPage();
        }
    
        public function mount()
        {
            $this->instance='';
            $this->job='';
            // $this->tasks=[];
            $this->instances=[];
            $this->jobs=[];
        }
    
        public function updatedinstance()
        {
            $in = Task::find($this->instance);
    
            if(!empty($in))
            {
                $tasks= Task::whereIn('process_status', ['new','processing'])
                ->where('instance','like', $in->instance)
                ->orderByRaw('FIELD(process_status, "new", "processing")asc')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
                ->paginate(50)
                ;
            }
            else
            {
                $tasks= Task::whereIn('process_status', ['new','processing'])
                ->orderByRaw('FIELD(process_status, "new", "processing")asc')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
                ->paginate(50)
                ;
            }
    
            return $tasks;
    
        }
    
        public function updatedjob()
        {
    
            $in_job = Task::find($this->job);
    
            if(!empty($in_job))
            {
                $tasks = Task::whereIn('process_status', ['new','processing'])
                ->where('job', 'like', $in_job->job)
                ->orderByRaw('FIELD(process_status, "new", "processing")asc')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
                ->paginate(50);
            }
            else
            {
                $tasks = Task::whereIn('process_status', ['new','processing'])
                ->orderByRaw('FIELD(process_status, "new", "processing")asc')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
                ->paginate(50);
            }
    
            return $tasks;
        }
    
    
        public function render()
        {
            $this->instances = Task::whereIn('process_status', ['new','processing'])->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();
    
            $this->jobs = Task::whereIn('process_status', ['new','processing'])->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();
            $tasks = $this->updatedjob();
            $tasks = $this->updatedinstance();
    
            return view('livewire.table-todo',['tasks' => $tasks]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally apply both where-clauses using `when()`. The first argument here is exposed into the closure, which is useful for this particular case where you pass a model. If the first parameter to `when()` is truthy, it executes the closure. Otherwise, it does nothing.

You can also heavily clean up the code by reusing the same methods instead of having to repeat yourself.

```php
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\WithPagination;

use App\Models\Task;
use Livewire\Component;

class TableTodo extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $instance = '';
    public $job = '';
    public $jobs = [];
    public $instances = [];

    private $tasks = [];

    public function updatinginstance()
    {
        $this->resetPage();
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->instances = Task::whereIn('process_status', ['new', 'processing'])
                               ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
                               ->get();
        $this->jobs = Task::whereIn('process_status', ['new', 'processing'])
                          ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
                          ->get();
        $this->filterTask();
    }

    public function updatedInstance()
    {
        $this->filterTask();
    }

    public function updatedJob()
    {
        $this->filterTask();
    }

    public function filterTask() 
    {
        $job = Task::find($this->job);
        $instance = Task::find($this->instance);

        $tasks = Task::when($job, function($query, $job) {
                    return $query->where('job', 'LIKE', $job->job);
                })
                ->when($instance, function($query, $instance) {
                    return $query->where('instance','like', $instance->instance);
                })
                ->orderByRaw("FIELD(process_status, 'new', 'processing') ASC")
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
                ->paginate(50);

        $this->tasks = $tasks;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.table-todo', ['tasks' => $this->tasks]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I also solved it with a public variable named tasks unfortunately the public variables do not support the paginate method as collections @Qirel Error:Livewire component's [table-todo] public property [tasks] must be of type: [numeric, string, array, null, or boolean]. Only protected or private properties can be set as other types because JavaScript doesn't need to access them.

Comment: Fair point, but the idea is the same. You can pass it through the `render()` method instead (by passing it as a second parameter to `view()`).

Comment: sorry but I did not understand how to do it in practice @Qirel

Comment: I updated the answer to show that. Should work as the answer is now.